# Does an eFuse exist that latches off immediately (and does not reactivate) in case of a short-circuit?

Tags: fuses, latch, surge-protection

I've just discovered eFuses (from Texas Instruments + Toshiba + STMicro).

In case of a short-circuit on the output, MOS can be disabled in 150-500 ns by detecting a surge of current (called "fast-trip"), but after 30-100 μs the MOS is enabled again and a limited current is applied until the  thermal shut-down threshold disables the MOS.

In my case, the short-circuit is not with only few milli-ohms, but with a few ohms in other chips (MUX), so that the thermal threshold of the eFuse will be too late; the MUX will be destroy before that.

So my question is: does someone know of an eFuse not reactivating after this "fast-trip" current-surge detection?

Edit : 2 pictures added
[image: Fast Trip curves]
[image: My schematic]

Comment: So when *do* you want the eFuse to 'reactivate'? Ever?

Comment: Keep reading. Some have latched and recycle ,modes https://www.digikey.ca/en/articles/why-and-how-to-effectively-use-electronic-fuses

Comment: I want the eFuse to latch off with "fast-trip" short-circuit dectection, without trying to apply a limited current.

Comment: In the Digikey link, there is :  TPS26620, TCKE805 and STEF033. All are working without latch off in case of "fast-trip" short-circuit dectection, I'm looking for one doing that.

Comment: brhans, I want to reactivate the eFuse with a push putton for example, or with the power supply off - on.

Comment: Can you provide a circuit diagram or block diagram showing how you want to fit the fuse device in with the other components?

Comment: You could google crowbar circuits --- the functionality is close to what you describe but I don't think I understand your description well enough to know if it is close enough.

Comment: Thanks The Photon for your idea of crowbar circuits, I don't thinks it's what I need but I'm now working to understand how it works. I've added 2 pictures to be more precise in my need description.

Comment: I've written something wrong: "so that the thermal threshold of the eFuse will be too late; the MUX will be destroy before that." => It's not always true because Ron of eFuse will grow with limited current so thermal protection will be activated before MUX would have been destroyed (if eFuse limited current is allowed in MUX, here it's 0.5A max)